# What is the minimum number of circles of radius R1 that are required to cover a circle of radius R2 completely?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I researched on this question but could find questions similar to `number of circles of radius R1 that could fit in another circle of radius R2`. But can we effectively determine, using a standard procedure/algorithm, the minimum circles required to cover a larger circle `completely`?
PS: I was thinking of some optimal arrangement of the smaller circles in the larger one. And circles can (obviously) overlap.

Comment: A sort of "inverse problem" or "dual problem" to what you're considering is the [disk covering problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskCoveringProblem.html).

Comment: To answer that question, though: there is no "algorithm" currenly known that produces an optimal arrangement.

Comment: Packing problems are usually hard.  Depending on R1, R2, the arrangement can be quite irregular.  I see no reason for this to be different.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Is there any specific property if the ratio of radius is `PI`.?

Comment: Base on Wikipedia we know that 13 or more disks are required. That's all I can gather though

Answer (score 2):

This is the dual version of the [Disk covering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_covering_problem). There are some results in this [article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2371320?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), and a visualisation for some values of $R_1$ [here](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/circovcir/).

Comment: Thanx for answering. Can I get to know any specific property if the ratio of radius is `PI`.